# Specify Permalink and Post Description with Blogger API

Tags: api, google-apps-script, blogger

I am **creating new posts** on **Blogger** with the **API**.

I am able to set the title and content.

But, I am **not able to set** the **permanent link(slug)** and **search description** for the posts.

For slug, I have tried sending **url** parameter in the insert POST request but it didn't work.

I have found an option from documentation which might be useful:

- customMetaData - string - The JSON metadata for the post.

But, I don't know how to send metadata using JSON.

My Code:

```js
var postUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId/posts";
  postUrl = postUrl.replace("blogId",blogId);
  var options = {
    method:"post",
    contentType:"application/json",
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      title: title,
      content: content,
      url: url,
      description: description
    })
  }
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(postUrl, options).getContentText();
  Logger.log(res)
```

Comment: Hello @Ranveer, would you mind sharing the code you have used? That would be of great help. Cheers!

Comment: Updated the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL and customMetaData option in Blogger API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503028/url-and-custommetadata-option-in-blogger-api)

Comment: Actually, the other question is also mine. I tried that approach but got stuck in that approach and so I asked that question.

Comment: Nobody helped? Have you solved the problem by yourself? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, I was not able to solve this problem.